# converting mysql sub queries to join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am new to mysql database , and i am trying to create a query which uses joins.
The present Query which i have written is  taking 1 second of time to execute , i have done reasearch and found out joins to be best solution for  reducing time of execution  ,

the query what i am using is:

```
SELECT count(1) as total 
FROM `mytable` 
where pid IN (
     SELECT pid FROM `maps` 
     where `node_id` = (
          SELECT nid FROM shop 
          WHERE value = 'selling' 
            and parent = '170' 
            and  tid = 1
          )
     and  tid = 1
) 
and `pnumber` IN (
     select pnumber 
     FROM users_pro 
     where value = 'hulo' 
     and  tid = 1
)
and tid = 1
```

Please , little help will be most appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: Hm, `limit 1` without `ORDER BY`... To me that means 'a random record', do you have other requirements about your `nid`?

Comment: @Wrikken no its just 1 for nid

Comment: please elaborate: what if there are 2 or more different `nid`'s in the inner query that satisfy the requirements?

Comment: @Wrikken  , thanks for the reply , I am getting only one {nid} for that inner subquery , there will not be more than 1

Comment: So, we can just _ignore_ the `limit 1` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(distinct mytable.*) as total 
FROM mytable 
JOIN maps
  ON mytable.pid = maps.pid
  AND maps.tid = mytable.tid
JOIN shop
  ON maps.node_id = shop.nid
  AND shop.value = 'selling' 
  AND shop.parent = '170' 
  AND shop.tid = mytable.tid
JOIN users_pro 
  ON mytable.pnumber = users_pro.pnumber
  AND users_pro.value = 'hulo' 
  AND users_pro.tid = mytable.tid
WHERE mytable.tid=1
```